# Trigger to automatically add tuples to relation

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-database

I'm trying to create a trigger on SQLITE to automatically add tuples to another table when something is added to a certain table, but firstly, I want to check if what I'm adding belongs to another third table.

This is my trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS atualizaBibliotecas;

CREATE TRIGGER atualizaBibliotecas
AFTER INSERT ON FoiComprado
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE 
    WHEN 
    (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM Album 
        WHERE idItem = NEW.idItem
    ) <> 0
    THEN INSERT INTO Possui(idItem, email, dataAquisicao) VALUES(11,'aaaa@bbbb.com', '2019-05-14');
END;
```

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
Error: near line 8: near "INSERT": syntax error
```

LINE 8:

```
CREATE TRIGGER atualizaBibliotecas
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER atualizaBibliotecas
AFTER INSERT ON FoiComprado
FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN 
    (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM Album 
        WHERE idItem = NEW.idItem
    ) <> 0
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Possui(idItem, email, dataAquisicao) VALUES(11,'aaaa@bbbb.com', '2019-05-14');
END;
```

Comment: Silly me... This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't support control-flow logic in its triggers.  You can express this as a conditional `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO Possui (idItem, email, dataAquisicao)  
   SELECT 11, 'aaaa@bbbb.com', '2019-05-14'
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Album a WHERE a.idItem =  NEW.idItem);
```

I find it surprising that you are hardcoding `11` for the insert.  I would expect `NEW.idITEM`.

Comment: But I've done something similar like

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS validaCompraAlbum;

CREATE TRIGGER validaCompraAlbum
  BEFORE INSERT ON foiComprado
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN 
    SELECT CASE 
    WHEN 
    (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM 
        (
        SELECT email 
        FROM FoiComprado, Comprou
        WHERE Comprou.idCompra= NEW.idCompra
        INTERSECT 
        SELECT email 
        FROM Possui
        WHERE idItem = NEW.idItem
        )       
    ) <> 0 
    THEN RAISE (ROLLBACK, 'Utilizador ja possui este album')
    END;
END;

and this works

Comment: And the hardcoded 11 (and the rest) is just for testing purposes :)